# Assigning local reference to global

Tags: javascript, global-variables, local-variables

here's what I can't understand.

I have this function here

```
function foo(){
let a = {a:1};
window.a = a; 
}
```

as you can see, this assign to `a` an object, so a reference to it, and then it creates a new property on the window object that contains this reference. If the `a` variable is local, it's reference point to an address in the stack, so, how can I access `a` from window, also out of the function, when the stack is cleaned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the a variable is local, it's reference point to an address in the stack

No. While a variable might be allocated on a stack containing the reference, what it references (the object) is likely allocated on "the heap", as - as you've noticed - it's lifetime is not known and as such must be managed by the garbage collector and cannot be stack-allocated.

That said the "stack" vs. "heap" distinction is not quite reflecting the reality of modern JIT-compilers.

Comment: thank you so much :) Can you advice me some references to clear the concept of heap and stack?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [V8 blog](https://v8.dev/blog/trash-talk), they have some in-depth articles about garbage collection (-> not one heap, but multiple generations), async functions (-> variables on the heap), also you might wanna have a look at their optimizing compiler (TurboFan) which makes variables and objects disappear ;) ... Unfortunatey there is no single simple reference (cause it's complicated)